# JFrame, Error Cannot make a static reference of the non-static field

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I am trying to set the data variable from SerialRead method but I got "Cannot make a static reference of the non-static field Etiqueta2", Eclipse said that I should make Etiqueta2 static but it doesnt show the data in the Jlabel.

```
public class Final extends JFrame
{

    //Crea Elementos de la interfaz
    JLabel Etiqueta=new JLabel();
    JTextField Texto=new JTextField();
    JButton Boton=new JButton();
    JLabel Etiqueta1=new JLabel();
    JLabel Etiqueta2=new JLabel();
    JButton Boton1=new JButton();




    public Final()
    {
        super();
        // Crea la interfaz

        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Lectura y escritura de datos");
        setSize(380,200);
        //Propiedades de los elementos del Frame
        // Etiqueta
        Etiqueta.setBounds(20,50, 100, 20);
        Etiqueta.setText("Enviar un digito");
        add(Etiqueta);
        // Caja de texto
        Texto.setBounds(120,50,100, 20);
        add(Texto);
        // Boton
        Boton.setBounds(250,50,100, 20);
        Boton.setText("Enviar");
        add(Boton);
        // Etiqueta 1
        Etiqueta1.setBounds(20,80, 100, 20);
        Etiqueta1.setText("Leer un digito");
        add(Etiqueta1);
        // Etiqueta2
        Etiqueta2.setBounds(120,80,100, 20);
        add(Etiqueta2);
        // Boton 1
        Boton1.setBounds(250,80,100, 20);
        Boton1.setText("Leer");
        add(Boton1);
        // Boton de cierre   
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
    {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        }
        else
        {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

            if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                new SerialReader(in, Etiqueta2).execute();
                (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
        }     
    }

    /** */
public static class SerialReader extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {   //Final frame = new Final();

    private InputStream in;
    private JLabel label;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in, JLabel label) {
        this.in = in;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        String data = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        label.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            String data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
            System.out.println(data);
            publish(data);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

    /** */
    public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
    {
          **** output code ****
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {

        try
        {
            (new Final()).connect("COM7");
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to setText on the Etiqueta2 Label to show the data variable?

Thanks

**EDIT3:** I updated the code with the swingworker, execute and println to watch the data in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerialReader` is declared as `static`, therefore it can not access the instance fields of the outer `Final` class, as it's possible to create an instance of `SerialReader` without needing an instance of `Final` first.

Instead, you should pass a reference of the `JLabel` you want to update to the `SerialReader` class

```
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{   //Final frame = new Final();

    InputStream in;
    private JLabel label;

    public SerialReader ( InputStream in, JLabel label ) {
         this.label = label;
         //...
```

Then you would use this to update from within your run method.

You could simply make the class non-static, but that comes down to your needs

The other problem you have is Swing is not thread safe, so it's actually unadvisable to call `setText` on the instance of `JLabel` from within the `run` method.

Typically, I'd recommend using a `SwingWorker`, as it has methods that allow you to `publish` results from the background thread and `process` them within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, allowing you to safely modify the state of the UI, but in this case, you could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

```
    public void run ()
    {
        //...
        try
        {
            while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
            {
                //...
                SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Etiqueta2.setText(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
```

But you may need to make `data` `final`, which could cause more issues, which in that case, I'd just use a `SwingWorker` instead.

Take a closer look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

## `SwingWorker` Example...

```
public static class SerialReader extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {   //Final frame = new Final();

    private InputStream in;
    private JLabel label;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in, JLabel label) {
        this.in = in;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        String data = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        label.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            String data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
            publish(data);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Runnable `SwingWorker` example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label);
            new ClockWorker(label).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static class ClockWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        protected static final DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm.ss SSS a");

        private JLabel label;

        public ClockWorker(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            label.setText(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                publish(DF.format(new Date()));
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

## "Faked" `InputStream` example...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Final extends JFrame {

    //Crea Elementos de la interfaz
    JLabel Etiqueta = new JLabel();
    JTextField Texto = new JTextField();
    JButton Boton = new JButton();
    JLabel Etiqueta1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel Etiqueta2 = new JLabel("Banana");
    JButton Boton1 = new JButton();

    public Final() {
        super();
        // Crea la interfaz

        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Lectura y escritura de datos");
        setSize(380, 200);
        //Propiedades de los elementos del Frame
        // Etiqueta
        Etiqueta.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);
        Etiqueta.setText("Enviar un digito");
        add(Etiqueta);
        // Caja de texto
        Texto.setBounds(120, 50, 100, 20);
        add(Texto);
        // Boton
        Boton.setBounds(250, 50, 100, 20);
        Boton.setText("Enviar");
        add(Boton);
        // Etiqueta 1
        Etiqueta1.setBounds(20, 80, 100, 20);
        Etiqueta1.setText("Leer un digito");
        add(Etiqueta1);
        // Etiqueta2
        Etiqueta2.setBounds(120, 80, 100, 20);
        add(Etiqueta2);
        // Boton 1
        Boton1.setBounds(250, 80, 100, 20);
        Boton1.setText("Leer");
        add(Boton1);
        // Boton de cierre   
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    void connect(String portName) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("...");
        new SerialReader(new FakeInputStream(), Etiqueta2).execute();

//      CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
//      if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
//          System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
//      } else {
//          CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
//
//          if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
//              SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
//              serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
//
//              InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
//              OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
//
//              new SerialReader(in, Etiqueta2).execute();
//              (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();
//
//          } else {
//              System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
//          }
//      }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SerialReader extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        private InputStream in;
        private JLabel label;

        public SerialReader(InputStream in, JLabel label) {
            this.in = in;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            String data = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            label.setText(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                String data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
                System.out.println(data);
                publish(data);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            (new Final()).connect("COM7");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class FakeInputStream extends InputStream {

        private Random rnd = new Random();

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return 33 + rnd.nextInt(125-33); // Ascii characters
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution with the SwingUtiltiies, it did not show any error but the Label did not show anything, What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `setLayout(null);` isn't going to help, but since you've not provided an example of your `SwingWorker`, I have no idea why it didn't work

Comment: Right under `setVisible`.  Your example doesn't use a `SwingWorker`, it uses `SwingUtilities` AND you still have a static/non-static error, as `Etiqueta2` can't be referenced from inside your `SerialReader` class...so I have no idea how that would even compile...

Comment: Then it's likely to be an issue with the layout or you're shadowing your variables

Comment: I updated my code with your example but nothing happens unless I am doing it wrong and also i import two 2 libraries javax.swing.SwingWorker and java.util.List;

Comment: yeah I updated it and i forgot to said i also updated the connect method with (new Thread(new SerialReader(in, Etiqueta2))).start();

Comment: Oh, and did you call `SwingWorker#execute` to "start" the worker?

Comment: Change `(new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();` to `new SerialReader(in, Etiqueta2).execute();`

Comment: I changed new SerialReader(in, Etiqueta2).execute(); and  also add the system.println(data) and the console show the data but the UI is still in blank

Comment: The UI may not be able to keep up with the speed of the output (more to the point, the `SwingWorker` may not be pushing updates to the UI), try adding a `Thread.sleep(1)` after the `publish` call

Comment: Added Thread.sleep(1); after publish(Data); and nothing happens, There is a way to "save" a variable when the information arrive?

Comment: Okay, finally, I have an example which uses a "fake" `InputStream` to execute your code, and it outputs okay for me...

Comment: Still not working my friend, now the console isnt working now. :( i dont know what to do im new in java

Comment: I also tried your fake example and it is working but the max length is 8, i think the problem is the rxtx api ?

Comment: I don't know, since I can't run it, but since every thing else "seems" to be running okay, that's where I'd start.  May do a simple test without the UI and just get the hang of reading/writing to the streams

Comment: Its work without the UI, I simulate a serial port COM7 and send the strings with hyperterminal, the console show the data but the UI dont.

Comment: The only other thing I can think is the `null` isn't updating the UI.  You could try using `label.repaint()` after you call `label.setText(...)`

Comment: I test it with repain and I saw something... The console is showing a lot of blank(empty) spaces, when I send the data with hyperterminal its show in the console for 1 second or less... console is still dropping empty spaces... maybe the UI got the value but they pass throught the label too quickly

Answer (score 2):

`SerialReader` is a static inner class of `Final` and due to this can't access any non-static fields in `Final`. Since you apparently don't use `SerialReader` outside of `Final` just make it non-static (could even be a private inner class). Same applies for `SerialWriter`.