# How can I make my JTextArea dynamically update based on the results of a continuous scan of the USB ports?

Tags: java

A recent project I began is almost complete. However, I am struggling to update the JTextArea with the same messages my console is outputting:

"Correct device is not plugged in. Waiting and trying again."

"No devices are plugged in. Waiting and trying again."

"Removable Device Directory: " + directory

"SAVED TO: " + destination

etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

ENTIRE CODE

```
/* ImageReaderGUI.java Copyright 2019
 *
 * Written by Noah Shaw
 *
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.samuelcampos.usbdrivedetector.USBDeviceDetectorManager; // Special thanks to this guy!
import net.samuelcampos.usbdrivedetector.USBStorageDevice;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ImageReader {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    static USBStorageDevice main = null;

    /*
     * Launch the application
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageReader window = new ImageReader();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Create the application
     */
    public ImageReader()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    /*
     * Initialize the contents of the frame
     */
    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 440, 560);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Image Reader");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(12, 13, 398, 499);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
        startBtn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        startBtn.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            { 
                frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
                poll();
                execute();
            }
        });
        startBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        startBtn.setBounds(12, 462, 374, 24);
        panel.add(startBtn);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(12, 13, 374, 436);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(textArea);
        setUIAppearance();
    }

    /*
     * Set the look and feel of the application to the system's look and feel
     */
    private void setUIAppearance()
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InstantiationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Polls the USB ports on the computer until the correct removable storage device is plugged in
     */
    private void poll()
    {
        boolean scanning = true;
        while(scanning)
        {
            USBDeviceDetectorManager manager = new USBDeviceDetectorManager();
            List<USBStorageDevice> usbStorageDevices = manager.getRemovableDevices();
            if(usbStorageDevices.size() >= 1)
            {
                for(USBStorageDevice device : usbStorageDevices)
                {
                    if(device.getDeviceName().equals("F")) // Will need the name of SD card
                    {
                        scanning = false;
                        main = device;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Correct device is not plugged in. Waiting and trying again." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                              textArea.append("Correct device is not plugged in. Waiting and trying again.");
                            }
                          });
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No devices are plugged in. Waiting and trying again.");
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Initialize the JFileChooser
     */
    private void execute()
    {
        // Set the current directory to the root directory of the removable device and the title of the file chooser window
        File directory = main.getRootDirectory();
        // Get the current directory and print it to the console
        System.out.println("Removable Device Directory: " + directory);
        final String[] EXTENSIONS = new String[] {"png", "jpg", "jpeg"}; // Acceptable file extensions
        final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() // Filter all files that have an acceptable file extension
        {
            public boolean accept(final File directory, final String name)
            {
                for(final String ext : EXTENSIONS)
                {
                    if(name.endsWith("." + ext))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        saveAndPrint(directory, IMAGE_FILTER);
    }

    /*
     * Save and print each image
     */
    private void saveAndPrint(File aDirectory, FilenameFilter aFilenameFilter)
    {
        String saveDirectory = null;
        int count = 0;
        // If the directory is a directory, begin the save
        if(aDirectory.isDirectory())
        {
            save(aDirectory, aFilenameFilter, saveDirectory, count);
            print(aDirectory, aFilenameFilter);
        }
        // No selection was made in the file chooser
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Selection");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Save each image
     */
    private void save(File aDirectory, FilenameFilter aFilenameFilter, String aSaveDirectory, int aCount)
    {
        for(final File f : aDirectory.listFiles(aFilenameFilter))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a buffered image of the file
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
                // Format the date that the image was last modified in dd_MM_yyyy format
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
                String lastModified = dateFormat.format(f.lastModified());
                // Save the image in a new destination with the last modified date appended to the front of the name of the file
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Pictures"));
                fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Save");
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if(aCount == 0 && fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    aSaveDirectory = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                    aCount = -1;
                }
                System.out.println(aSaveDirectory);
                File destination = new File(aSaveDirectory + "\\" + lastModified + "_" + f.getName());
                // Print to the console where the image was saved
                System.out.println("SAVED TO: " + destination);
                ImageIO.write(img, f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1), destination);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Print each image to the default printer
     */
    private void print(File aDirectory, FilenameFilter aFilenameFilter)
    {
        for(final File f : aDirectory.listFiles(aFilenameFilter))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a buffered image of the file
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
                // Create the print job
                PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                printJob.setPrintable(new Printable()
                    {
                        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException
                        {
                            pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
                            pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT); // Portrait orientation
                            Paper paper = pageFormat.getPaper();
                            paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
                            pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
                            // No page
                            if(pageIndex != 0)
                            {
                                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                            }
                            // Translate the image to (0,0)
                            graphics.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());
                            // Center the image on the page
                            graphics.drawImage(img,  ((int)pageFormat.getImageableWidth() / 2) - (img.getWidth() / 2),  ((int)pageFormat.getImageableHeight() / 2) - (img.getHeight() / 2),  img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(),  null);
                            return PAGE_EXISTS;
                            }
                    });
                // Print each image to the default printer
                try
                {
                    printJob.print();
                }
                catch(PrinterException printException)
                {
                    printException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently using a thread, but I don't believe it is correct:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                              textArea.append("Correct device is not plugged in. Waiting and trying again.");
                            }
                          });
```

Comment: Use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html); [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761883/jframe-error-cannot-make-a-static-reference-of-the-non-static-field/29761946#29761946)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you possibly provide an example of how it would be used in my program? I just don't understand how everything (the thread, SwingWorker, publish(), doInBackground(), etc) is supposed to interact.